# adding fields to a specific position of the file for each record in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a fixed width file ,which will have two record types 10 and 20. record type will be in the first two characters of the file. Each column have a specific width assigned to it.

```
record type-10, record length-45;
record type-20, record length-24
```

below is the Input file-test.dat has two records, first record- record type-10 and second record record type-20:

**INPUT:**

```
1023457 lenovo houseno-67panjagutta Hyderabad
206789  Vega   Bangalore
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1023457 lenovo houseno-67panjagutta Hyderabad
206789  Vega   |||||||||||||||||||||Bangalore
```

i want to add pipe to record type-20 so that both the record types will have same record length 45. here address field is missing in record type 20, so i want to add 21 pipe characters(address field) in the record type-20 to make both the record types have same length.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a few lines of concise, testable sample input AND expected output.

Answer (score 0):

run command

```
awk -f append.awk test
```

**append.awk** as follows

```
#! /bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
max=45;
FS=""
}
$1$2 == 20 && length <45{
    FS=" ";
    $0=$0;
    len=length;
    for(i=1; i<=max-len; i++){
        $3="|"$3
    };
    print $0;
    FS="";
    next
} 
1
```

**Output**

```
1023457 lenovo houseno-67panjagutta Hyderabad
206789 Vega ||||||||||||||||||||||||Bangalore
```

Comment: Hi Chet, thanks for the reply. if we want to add single field we can perform by above. if we want to add multiple fields in a file. do we have any other approach.  example- `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {$19="  "$19} 1' file`.  if i want to add 25 spaces/pipe in 3rd field and 6th field 10 spaces and so on in a file as above for multiple fields.

Comment: yes but how do you want to split the "|" in case of multiple fields? can you edit the question accordingly pls with a input?

Comment: Hi Chet,after 87th column iam adding 26 spaces and 113rd column adding 26  spaces and 116th column adding 20 spaces in test2.dat file from test.dat. below is the command i am using, can you suggest to improve the below command. 
`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {$88="                          "$88} 1 {$114="                          "$114} 1 {$116="                    "$116} 1' test.dat > test2.dat`

Comment: is there a maximum length limitation(45) of the new o/p?